# HDF5 (C interface) consumes all RAM with repeated calls to H5Oget_info_by_name

Tags: c++, c, hdf5, ram, massif

I am seeing weird behaviour from my HDF5 code in C++ (using the C interface). It maxes out the RAM usage on my system, but then seems to continue running just fine. I am not sure if the point where it stops allocating more RAM is a coincidence or if it is expected internal behaviour of some buffers or some such to do this. Anyway the problem is that if some *other* application wants to use some RAM then it can't, and the whole system starts thrashing and locks up.

I ran the code through `valgrind --tool=massif` and `massif-visualizer` to try and see what is happening, and got the output below:

[image: massif-visualizer_output]

Looking through the call chain in a typical snapshot (displayed in the image), it looks like it is occurring in one of my functions `op_func`, which is called repeatedly by `H5Literate` as I iterate through a group in the HDF5 file to identify all the datasets that it contains.

But this function isn't even reading or writing any significant data! All it does is call `H5Oget_info_by_name` repeatedly to query for dataset names! So I don't see why this should be consuming all my RAM. In case I am doing something stupid, here is the code for the function that is repeatedly called:

```
        inline herr_t op_func (hid_t loc_id, const char *name_in, const H5L_info_t *,
                void *operator_data)
        {
            herr_t          return_val = 0;
            H5O_info_t      infobuf; 
            std::vector<std::string> &od = *static_cast<std::vector<std::string> *> (operator_data);
            std::string name(name_in);

            H5Oget_info_by_name (loc_id, name.c_str(), &infobuf, H5P_DEFAULT);

            switch (infobuf.type)
            {
                case H5O_TYPE_GROUP:
                {
                    break;  
                }
                case H5O_TYPE_DATASET:
                {
                    std::string str(name);
                    if (name.find("_isvalid") == std::string::npos)
                        od.push_back(std::string(name));
                    break;
                }
                case H5O_TYPE_NAMED_DATATYPE:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            return return_val;
        }
```

As you can see it is pretty simple, I am just harvesting names and pushing them onto a vector of strings. It could probably use some better error checking, but it seems to be working just fine aside from this RAM issue.

Am I doing something dumb to cause a memory leak here? Or is HDF5 being REALLY aggressive in its internal buffering, and buffering up way more information than I realise? Perhaps I just need to tell it to clear some buffers or do garbage collection or something?

Comment: More code is probably needed to find the problem, please write a [mcve] which is good for yourself to help you spot the problem, and for Stack Overflow users to help you find it too.

Comment: Hmm well would be rather hard and I was just hoping to find a HDF5 expert who knew how this works. It looks highly unlikely to me that the rest of my code is relevant. I suspect that what I see has to do with the behaviour of the metadata cache, which can apparently grow without limit: https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/Advanced/MetadataCache/index.html. There seems to be some options for controlling the behaviour of the metadata cache so I suspect that tweaking these in the correct way might be the solution.

Comment: Forget about HDF5, it's not the problem for sure.

Comment: I am now very sure that isn't the case. It is HDF5. If I comment out the call to H5Oget_info_by_name then I don't see this explosion of RAM usage. I also found this thread discussing performance issues with it: https://lists.hdfgroup.org/pipermail/hdf-forum_lists.hdfgroup.org/2011-October/005205.html, which seems to suggest that one can somehow specify more carefully what information H5Oget_info_by_name should collect. There also seems to have been a similar issue in PyTables with this function: https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/402

Comment: How many times is `H5Oget_info_by_name()` being called? Is there a way to deallocate possibly allocated data in the `infobuf` structure?

Comment: It is called zillions of times, I have hundreds of hdf5 files with hundreds of datasets in each of them, and I am iterating through the whole lot. As for deallocating info in infobuf, I have no idea. But it also looks like this could go much faster if I get the info I need some other way. I just need to know whether an object is a dataset or not. But I don't think the "lightweight" ways of getting such data have actually made it into the public API yet, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166121/discussion-between-iharob-al-asimi-and-ben-farmer).

Comment: Sorry got distracted on something else for a while. But anyway I "solved" it. Seems like HDF5 does some pretty extreme caching/buffering, even when you just query the files for dataset and group names, but these can be cleaned out by just closing the files. So previously I had my hundreds of HDF5 files open at once to do my operations, whereas now I open and close them one at a time, over and over again, which doesn't seem to hurt performance and avoids the RAM issue. I will write up an answer with more details later.